# sklearn roc curve function threshold not working correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

From the documentation of sklearn's roc_curve (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html), I understand that the first threshold value is chosen as max(predictions)+1 to ensure that the curve starts at the origin. However, for some reason, sometimes the function does not exhibit this behavior. Simple working example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
pred = [0.54836529, 0.42196323, 0.38207147, 0.37080573, 0.36138288]
true = [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(true,pred)
print(thresholds)
>>>>> [0.54836529 0.31656115]
```

Which is simply max(pred) without the +1 added. I understand that in my use case a FPR is meaningless, but that should not lead to this unwanted behavior. Furthermore, it also shows up when having both positives and negatives in my `true` list:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
pred = [0.54836529, 0.42196323, 0.38207147, 0.37080573, 0.36138288, 0.33759752,
 0.32965766, 0.31987022, 0.32147135, 0.31954395, 0.31823744, 0.31692976,
 0.31665266, 0.31661259, 0.31656115, 0.31656341, 0.31656842, 0.31656899,
 0.3165681,  0.31656433, 0.31656114, 0.31655793, 0.31655027, 0.31655875,
 0.31655297, 0.31655229, 0.31655317, 0.31654948, 0.31654313, 0.31656347]
true = [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1. ,1. ,1. ,1. ,1. ,1., 1.,
 1.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.]
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(true,pred)
print(thresholds)
>>>>>[0.54836529 0.31656433 0.31656347 0.31655027 0.31654313]
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Could someone try to reproduce this error?

Comment: I think it has to do with your version of scikit-learn. I had 0.19 and replicated your problem, however after updating I got the result expected by the documentation.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you :) I'll leave the question up in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: This look like this bug fix: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9790